# Redirect URL with parameter to version without parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Or in other words, strip the `?PageSpeed=noscript` from any URL and 301 to the same version without the `?PageSpeed=noscript`

So `www.example.com/acme?PageSpeed=noscript`

Would go to `www.example.com/acme`

or `www.example.com/pots/warehouse/house?PageSpeed=noscript`

to `www.example.com/pots/warehouse/house`

It shouldn't matter was the subfolder is. The answers I found referenced specific subfolders

I'm trying to achieve this using apache htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Rule to strip `PageSpeed=noscript` query parameter from your URLs :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PageSpeed=noscript$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```